# What does the phrase "Window shopping" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I heard the following line in an English-speaking movie :

> *We bought very little today, and mainly did a lot of **window shopping**.*

What does the speaker mean by *window shopping*?

Comment: What does your dictionary say?

Comment: A Google search for **[window shopping define](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&ie=UTF-8&source=android-browser&q=loathe+definition&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en-US&q=window+shopping+define+)** gives many results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*window shopping* stands when you browse the shops without actually buying. (Not just because of lack of money. A lot of people like passing around the shops without buying a thing.)

Example of *window shopping*:

[image: example]

Dialogue example:

> — What else did you buy?
>   — Couple of stuff but the rest was just ***window shopping***.
>   — Ah, you were looking at stuff but you didn't buy them anyway.